# Symfony 2 - Loading roles from database

Tags: php, security, symfony

My roles are stored in the database and I am trying to load them dynamically upon login. What I'm doing is querying for the roles and setting them on the user object in my user provider as seen here:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->getQuery()
    ;

    try {
        // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
        // if there is no record matching the criteria.
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();

        // Permissions
        $permissions = $this->_em->getRepository('E:ModulePermission')->getPermissionsForUser($user);

        if ($permissions !== null) {
            foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                $name = strtoupper(str_replace(" ", "_", $permission['name']));

                $role = "ROLE_%s_%s";

                if ($permission['view']) {
                    $user->addRole(sprintf($role, $name, 'VIEW'));
                }

                if ($permission['add']) {
                    $user->addRole(sprintf($role, $name, 'ADD'));
                }

                if ($permission['edit']) {
                    $user->addRole(sprintf($role, $name, 'EDIT'));
                }

                if ($permission['delete']) {
                    $user->addRole(sprintf($role, $name, 'DELETE'));
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active admin Entity:User object identified by "%s".', $username), null, 0, $e);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

And the user entity:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    ....

    protected $roles;

    ....

    public function __construct() {
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
        $this->roles = array();
    }


    ....


    public function getRoles() {
        $roles = $this->roles;

        // Ensure we having something
        $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function addRole($role) {
        $role = strtoupper($role);
        $roles = $this->getRoles();
        if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
            return $this;
        }

        if (!in_array($role, $roles, true)) {
            $this->roles[] = $role;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function hasRole($role) {
        $role = strtoupper($role);
        $roles = $this->getRoles();
        return in_array($role, $roles, true);
    }
}
```

This works fine and dandy and I see the correct roles when I do:

```
$this->get('security.context')->getUser()->getRoles()
```

The problem (I think), is that the token does not know about these roles. Because calling getRoles() on the token is showing only ROLE_USER, which is the default role.

It seems to me that the token is being created before the user is loaded by the UserProvider. I've looked through a lot of the security component but I can't for the life of me find the right part of the process to hook into to set these roles correctly so that the token knows about them.

**Update** Following the Load roles from database doc works fine, but this does not match my use case as shown here. My schema differs as each role has additional permissions (view/add/edit/delete) and this is why I am attempting the approach here. I don't want to have to alter my schema just to work with Symfony's security. I'd rather understand why these roles are not properly bound (not sure the correct doctrine word here) on my user object at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here stemmed from the fact that I thought I was implementing

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
```

but wasn't (as you can see in the original question, I forgot to add it to my class definition). I'm leaving this here for people if they come across it. All you need is to implement this interface, and add the following method to your user entity.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
    if ($user instanceof User) {
    // Check that the roles are the same, in any order
        $isEqual = count($this->getRoles()) == count($user->getRoles());
        if ($isEqual) {
            foreach($this->getRoles() as $role) {
                $isEqual = $isEqual && in_array($role, $user->getRoles());
            }
        }
        return $isEqual;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you may not be aware of the built in role management that Symfony offers.  Read the docs - [Managing roles in the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database)  It is actually quite simple to do what you want, all you need to do is implement an interface and define your necessary function.  The docs I linked to provide great examples.  Take a look.

UPDATE

It looks like the docs don't give you the `use` statement for the AdvancedUserInterface. Here it is:

```
// in your user entity
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
```

then in your role entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
```

The docs show you how to do the rest.

UPDATE

Take a look at this blog post, which shows how to create roles dynamically:

[Dynamically create roles](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-creating-dynamic-roles-using-roleinterface/)

Comment: My entity already extends AdvancedUserInterface and as you can see, I've set the roles on my user object. From what I can see I'm doing exactly what the docs suggest (I actually already read them).

Updated with relevant parts of user entity.

Comment: your protected `roles` variable should be type `ArrayCollection`, so in your `getRoles` function, you are redefining the `$roles` variable so it becomes a new array, with only one element (the ROLE_USER that you just assigned to it). [The doctrine docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) show you what you can do with an array collection, you might want to try the `toArray()` function, which converts the array collection to a php array.

Comment: also, does your Role class implement the `RoleInterface`? Could you also include your Role entity please?

Comment: From the docs "Notice that the Role class implements RoleInterface. This is because Symfony's security system requires that the User::getRoles method returns an array of either role strings or objects that implement this interface.". I'm returning an array of strings so this should not matter.

Comment: you are disregarding the same paragraph that you just quoted: "If Role didn't implement this interface, then User::getRoles would need to iterate over all the Role objects, call getRole on each, and create an array of strings to return." It does not look like you are doing this, so why not implement the RoleInterface?